# Calculating Polynomial Inverse with extended euclid in java

Tags: implementation, ntru

I'm trying to understand the NTRU-PKCS and therefor I wanted to code a naive Version of it. Now my Problem:

I tried to calculate the inverse of a Polynomial with an extended Version of euclids Algorithm. For some Polynomials my code works fine, but when I try it with the example from the NTRU-PKCS-Tutorial [NTRU-PKCS-Tutorial](https://assets.securityinnovation.com/static/downloads/NTRU/resources/NTRU-PKCS-Tutorial.pdf) it fails.
The Parameter are $N=11$ and $q = 32$;
The Polynomial $f$ is:

$
\begin{equation}
f= -x^{10}+x^9+x^6-x^4+x^2+x-1
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
f^{-1} \text{ mod }q = 30x^{10}+18x^9+20x^8+22x^7+16x^6+15x^5+4x^4+16x^3+6x^2+9x+5
\end{equation}
$

I really dont know why my code dont produce the right $f^{-1}$...

My Code:

```
    public PolynomialMod inverse(int N, int mod) {
    int loop = 0;
    PolynomialMod G = PolynomialMod.ZERO.clone();
    G.setNMod(N, mod);
    PolynomialMod newG = (PolynomialMod) PolynomialMod.ONE.clone();
    newG.setNMod(N, mod);
    int[] coeffR = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

    PolynomialMod quotient = null;
    PolynomialMod newR = this.clone();
    PolynomialMod R = this.getRing(N, mod);
    R.setNMod(N, mod);
    newR.setNMod(N, mod);

    while (!newR.equalsZero()) {
        if (DEBUG && loop != 0)
            System.out.println("loop: " + loop);
        if (DEBUG && loop == 0)
            System.out.println("========Initial Values========");
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("R   : " + R);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("newR: " + newR);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("Quotient: " + quotient);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("G   : " + G);
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("newG: " + newG);
        if (DEBUG && loop == 0)
            System.out.println("========Initial Values========");
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("\n");

        quotient = R.div(newR)[0];
        PolynomialMod help = R.clone();
        R = newR.clone();
        PolynomialMod times = quotient.times(newR);
        times.reduceBetweenZeroAndQ();
        newR = help.sub(times);
        newR.deleteLeadingZeros();
        newR.degree = newR.values.size() - 1;
        help = G.clone();
        G = newG.clone();
        PolynomialMod times2 = quotient.times(newG);
        times2.reduceBetweenZeroAndQ();
        newG = help.sub(times2);
        loop++;

    }
    if (R.getDegree() > 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("irreducible or multiple");

    return G.div(R)[0];
}
```

The output:

> ========Initial Values======== R   : [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] newR: [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ] Quotient: null G
>   : [ 0 ] newG: [ 1 ]
>   ========Initial Values========
>
> loop: 1 R   : [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ] newR: [ 30, 0, 2,
>   1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 1 ] Quotient: [ 31, 31 ] G   : [ 1 ] newG: [ 1, 1
>   ]
>
> loop: 2 R   : [ 30, 0, 2, 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 1 ] newR: [ 1, 31, 31,
>   1, 1, 0, 31, 0, 1 ] Quotient: [ 1, 31 ] G   : [ 1, 1 ] newG: [ 0, 0, 1
>   ]
>
> loop: 3 R   : [ 1, 31, 31, 1, 1, 0, 31, 0, 1 ] newR: [ 30, 31, 3, 2,
>   30, 30, 1, 2 ] Quotient: [ 0, 1 ] G   : [ 0, 0, 1 ] newG: [ 1, 1, 0,
>   31 ]

It happens, when I hit the 4th time the loop, cuz I have to calculate $2 * x = 1 \text{ mod }32$, but there is no such inverse of $2 \text{ mod }32$.
So the error have to happen before, but I really dont know where it happens.

---

**Edit:**

This error is not really a coding issue, because when I am calculating it with “Pen and Paper”, I get the exact same problem...

That’s why there has to be something wrong with my understanding of the extended Euclid, but I can't see why...

```
R_0:= x^N -1 
R_1:= f
R_n+1:= R_(n)- R_(n-1) div R(n-2)
```

looks right to me :/

Edit2:

Thanks for referring to the stackoverflow thread, I coded it like it was there in pseudocode, but it fails at the exact same step :(
Here my new code:

```
    public void inverseEuclid(int N, int mod) {
    PolynomialMod a= this.clone();
    PolynomialMod b= getRing(N,mod);
    PolynomialMod u = PolynomialMod.ONE.clone();
    u.setNMod(N, mod);
    PolynomialMod v1 = PolynomialMod.ZERO.clone();
    v1.setNMod(N, mod);
    PolynomialMod d = this.clone();
    PolynomialMod v3 = b.clone(); 

    while(!v3.equalsZero()) {
        System.out.println("========values========");
        System.out.println("d : "+d);
        System.out.println("v3: "+v3);
        PolynomialMod [] div = d.div(v3);
        PolynomialMod q =  div[0].clone();
        System.out.println("q : "+q);
        PolynomialMod t3 =  div[1].clone();
        System.out.println("t3: "+t3);
        PolynomialMod t1 = u.sub(q.convolution(v1));
        System.out.println("t1: "+t1);
        System.out.println("========values========\n\n");

        u = v1.clone();
        d = v3.clone();
        v1= t1.clone();
        v3=t3.clone();

        u.deleteLeadingZeros();
        d.deleteLeadingZeros();
        v1.deleteLeadingZeros();
        v3.deleteLeadingZeros();
    }
    PolynomialMod v = d.sub(a.convolution(u)).div(b)[0];
    System.out.println("u: "+u);
    System.out.println("v: "+v);
    System.out.println("d: "+d);
}
```

And here is my code for the euclidean division. I know this is not a coding-Forum, but I tried to implementations of euclid and I did it on paper, and the same error is ocurring... maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong...

```
    public PolynomialMod[] div(final PolynomialMod other) {
    if (other.isZero())
        throw new ArithmeticException("division by zero");
    final int degreeDifference = this.getDegree() - other.getDegree() + 1;
    if (degreeDifference <= 0)
        return new PolynomialMod[] { PolynomialMod.ZERO, this };

    final PolynomialMod rest = this.clone();
    final PolynomialMod quotient = new PolynomialMod(degreeDifference - 1, N, mod);
    final int otherDegree = other.getDegree();
    final int coeff = other.values.get(otherDegree);
    for (int i = degreeDifference - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final int q = MyMath.divMod(rest.values.get(otherDegree + i), coeff, mod);

        quotient.values.set(i, q);
        for (int j = 0; j <= otherDegree; j++) {
            int restHelp = ((rest.values.get(i + j) - q * other.values.get(j)) + mod) % mod;
            rest.values.set(i + j, restHelp);
        }
    }
    return new PolynomialMod[] { new PolynomialMod(quotient.values, N, mod),
            new PolynomialMod(rest.values, N, mod) };
}
```

Comment: I think this is on-topic because the asker says they get the same result with pencil and paper.

I would refer them to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421409/algorithm-for-computing-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial/2426520#2426520.

Comment: What does it mean to take the inverse of a polynomial modulo an integer? -1 for general cluelessness, I'm sick of silly questions like that from people who just have no idea what they are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> newR: [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ]

This polynomial is
$f = -x^{10} + x^9 + x^6 - x^4 + x^2 + x - 1$
where you wanted:

> $f=x^{10}+x^9+x^6−x^4+x^2+x−1$

The sign for the $x^{10}$ was opposite.

Your algorithm/code is actually correct. See the following calculation from sage:

```
sage: f

-x^10 + x^9 + x^6 - x^4 + x^2 + x - 1

sage: f_inv

30*x^10 + 18*x^9 + 20*x^8 + 22*x^7 + 16*x^6 + 15*x^5 + 4*x^4 + 16*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 9*x + 5

sage: (f*f_inv)%(x^11-1)%32

1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this was only a type O in this forum,

 R : [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
 newR: [ -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1 ]

newR is -x^10 (-x^0+x^+x^2+0x^3-x^4+0x^5+x^6+0x^7+0x^8+0x^9-x^10)

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment. Can you explain a bit more?

PS: if you correct this typo, you algorithm/code is correct. See the last part of my post. I did the calculation and it gives the right answer.

Comment: I found my mistake... I did the extended Euclid right, but I didnt choose the right Polynomial ring...

If I do this with q = 32 it's q= 2^5 so I have to calculate the Inverse in the Ring (R/2R) / (x^N -1). That was the Problem the whole time :(

I did not really understand what I was doing, now I ve a clue, when I reduce the coefficiants modulo 32 my algorithm fails, I ve to do it modulo 2 and after that I have to lift it to mod 32, as it is mentioned in 6.3.3.4 from the IEEE standard 1363.1-2008.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was as following:

The code works vor Polynomimals f(x) mod p, where p is prime (or gcd(p,coeff(f(x))) = 1), but I wanted the inverse modulo 32, which is in fact: 2^5, so I had to calculate the inverse mod 2 and then lift it to 2^5

The solution was in thread: [inverse of polynomials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421409/algorithm-for-computing-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial/2426520#2426520)